# grep doesn't produce the correct output when run on find command

Tags: linux, find, grep, regex

My task was to print the number of files in the current directory without using `ls` and `wc` commands.

I had typed the following lines in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -iname ".*" \) > list3
grep .* -c list3 > /dev/tty
```

The output is:

```
..:0
.6.1c.sh.swp:1
list3:22
```

while according to my understanding it should only be: `22`

Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 3):

#### Why `grep` isn't working correctly

It doesn't work because you need to tell `grep` that `.*` is the actual pattern you're looking for.

```
grep '.*' -c list3
```

If you don't use the single quotes, your shell will expand `.*` to the names of every file in your directory. This is called [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion). For example `a.txt b.txt`, so `grep` will see:

```
grep a.txt b.txt -c list3
```

Since [single quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) prevent expansion from happening, this is the way to go here.

---

#### Where your `grep` command is wrong:

By the way, you're going the wrong direction with the pattern here. The period `.` in a regular expression matches *any* character, and not the literal dot. See [the `man` page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) for more info. So your regex currently says: "find any character and then a sequence of any character". Quite redundant.

If you actually mean to match:

> *[dot] [anything else]*

… you need to escape the dot:

```
\.*
```

---

#### Where your `find` command could be improved:

I don't know what you mean to get rid of by

```
\( ! -iname ".*" \)
```

Your `find` command will prefix any file with the dot for the current working directory, thus you won't remove anything here. You could have just run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

To address the original problem, counting files without `ls` and `wc`:

Pure shell syntax:

```
files=0
for i in *; do
    [ -f "${i}" ] && files=$((files+1))
done
echo ${files}
```

To add hidden files to the count, just change the globbing settings prior to the `for` loop.

Alternatively: fun with `find` and shell expansion:

```
echo $(($(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '+1')))
```